# Why can't I set a background image in HTML?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I use spring boot and thymeleaf to create a simple web site but I can't set a background image in an html file. As a result, only the bgcolor is shown. The image is in the same folder same as the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

<title th:text="${title}" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#c7b39b" background="bk.jpg"/>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${title} + '!'" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use background image setting in css. Create 'image' directory in `resources/static` directory and move `bk.jpg` in it. If you are using spring security, you also need to grand access via ant matcher.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<style>
  body {
    background-image: url('../image/bk.jpg');
  }
</style>

<title th:text="${title}" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${title} + '!'" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Servers running server-side Java typically don't mix directories containing static files with directories containing template files.

Put the image file in a directory configured to serve static files. Replace `bk.jpg` with a URL that is mapped onto that directory.

---

Aside: The HTML `background` attribute was superseded — in 1996! — by CSS. Use CSS instead.